# Can I use my server disk space as the default location for alfresco repository?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I installed alfresco in a local machine. Unfortunately the machine has very low disk space of around 50GB. I need to upload documents around 100 GB.I have a server with extra disk space. Can I use this server space for the document upload so that these files will be accessible in alfresco share. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Stop Alfresco and move your `alf_data/contentstore` & `alf_data/contentstore.deleted`
to your server.

Add these properties to the **alfresco-global.properties**:

- `dir.contentstore=<path to the server>/contentstore`
- `dir.contentstore.deleted=<path to the server>/contentstore.deleted`

Comment: Now I cant login to share and explorer is not starting,Do i need to edit `dir.root=C:/Alfresco/alf_data` and server path should be given like this right( I am in windows) `dir.contentstore=\\servername/c/contentstore` ( the c is the name of the drive in server in which  I copied)

Comment: No you don't need to edit dir.root, using \\ and / isn't a nice way to set paths. Probably this is fine \\\\servername\\c\\contentstore or //servername/c/contentstore . Check your path in windows explorer if the path works. Normally /c/ should be /c$/

Comment: Is my server path correct, now I am not able to login and explorer is not started

Comment: How do I now if you path is correct? Test is yourself in windows explorer or in another filebrowser

Comment: I've posted the right possible syntax and even that syntax is testable

Comment: I am getting this error now `03010005 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/documentlibrary/repo.get.js': 03010004 03010005 Failed during processing of Google Docs subsystem status configuration from Alfresco: 03010004 Unable to retrieve Google Docs subsystem status from Alfresco: 404`

Comment: This is a fresh install and I didnt modify anything

Comment: I gave you an answer for your question. If it's a fresh install, delete your contentstore & contentstore deleted, indexes, db tables and run Alfresco

Comment: `c$` should I escape this with `\\` ?